# Is it possible to create context based on Entity in DialogFlow?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I want to create a dialog using DialogFlow the following way:

Say, I have the following Entity:

```
Entity loginType
   facebook
   google
```

An the following intent:

```
Intent: 
Training: I want to sign in using facebook
Output: Okay, I'm remebering that you want sign in using $loginType
Output Context: $loginType
```

Next I would like to have an Intent with the Input Context "facebook", so that the dialog is all about the logging in via facebook. 
Which means:

```
Intent:
Input Context: facebook
Training: I see an error while logging in.
Output: ...
```

But I cannot see a way an output is being set based on the parameter/entity during the Intent. Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Good question, and great application of contexts.
You're not able to do this through the Intent editor directly, but you *can* use fulfillment to do this. In your webhook, you can get the parameter for `loginType` and then create an output context with that name.